# Android Mobile App on Open Testing Stage - Can users Review? Can they buy in-app purchases? Can it be promoted?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, mobile-application

Trying to understand the open testing stage of new apps on the Google play store.

Just for my understanding, let's assume any new app is already approved for open testing by The Google play store platform.

1. Can any new app that is already approved for open testing to promote the open testing stage app on paid campaigns?
2. Can users who download this new open-testing app buy in-app purchases or yearly subscriptions?
3. Can this new app in the open-testing stage get reviews? if so, what happened to these reviews when the app promotes to the production stage?
4. let's say users paid for a yearly subscription to the app (which is still on open testing) - what happens to their subscription when it promotes to production?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Can any new app that is already approved for open testing to promote the open testing stage app on paid campaigns?

Yes, you have an open testing URL so you can promote it.

> 2. Can users who download this new open-testing app buy in-app purchases or yearly subscriptions?

Yes

> 3. Can this new app in the open-testing stage get reviews? if so, what happened to these reviews when the app promotes to the production stage?

It get reviews but it is not like production reviews, you will receive them privately to your email. the reviews will remain private after getting your app to production unless the user stop being beta tester and install production version.

> 4. let's say users paid for a yearly subscription to the app (which is still on open testing) - what happens to their subscription when it promotes to production?

Nothing, it will remain the same. also you should know that beta users remain testers even if you promote the open testing version to release, unless they stop being beta tester and install production version.

---

**Resources:**

[resource](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9845334?hl=en):

> Open testing: Create an open testing release to run a test with a large group and surface your app's test version on Google Play. If you run an open test, anyone can join your testing program and submit private feedback to you. Before choosing this option, make sure your app and store listing is ready to be visible on Google Play.

[resource](https://play.google.com/console/about/opentesting/):

> Start driving traffic
>
> Put your acquisition strategy to the test by making your pre-release app or game discoverable on Google Play
>
> Recruit more users into your open test by linking users straight to your details page on Google Play from any of your marketing channels
>
> Gather private feedback during open or closed tests and reply to testers directly in Play Console. Feedback during open or closed testing is only visible to you and will not affect your public rating.
>
> Reminder: if you’re testing a paid app using an open or closed test, testers still need to purchase it. If you’re testing a paid app using an internal test, testers can install your app for free.